# Visual Studio, Copy files to project directory problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio community 2017. coming from eclipse it was just enough to copy file to project directory and hit refresh then files were appearing in project explorer.

In VS, however when I copy some i.e. `*.cpp` or `*.h` in windows explorer to project directory, in VS solution explorer I can not see them. switching to folder view I see but can not include them into project.

via drag&drop to solution explorer (project view) I see them but are not part of project and in folder view and actual directory there is nothing.

what is going on with VS? How can I manually copy paste some files into project while they become part of project?

Comment: `project` / `add exising item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will note that there's nothing "going on" with Visual Studio in the sense that something is actually wrong with it, it's just that adding files to your project just requires you to actually *add* them to your solution. Essentially, it allows you to add miscellaneous files to your folders without automatically including them in your build project (for example, if you're working with some test images/files).

To add files/folders to your project you simply right click on your project in the **Solution Explorer** and then go to **Add > Existing Item...**. Then, it's just a matter of selecting one (or Ctrl + A/Shift Clicking to select all/multiple files) and then it will add them to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the solution explorer pane, click on the show all files button,
[image: solution explorer menu]

it will reveal all files including your pasted file,
Right click on your file and select "include in project".

Comment: You however have to stop debugging before carrying out the actions